# Error replacing StoragePool disk - not supported

Tags: windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, hyper-v-server-2016

I can't replace hard disks in my existing StoragePool, it fails when adding new disks.

My question seems similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/871726/unable-to-add-a-physical-disk-to-a-storage-spaces-storage-pool-but-can-add-it-to) one, but that can't be the answer, because I've been using it for over a year now and just want to change some of my disks.

I had the following drives in the pool

```
FriendlyName         HealthStatus MediaType BusType Usage       Size
------------         ------------ --------- ------- -----       ----
WDNVME256GB-1        Healthy      SCM       NVMe    Auto-Select 233 GB
WDNVME256GB-2        Healthy      SCM       NVMe    Auto-Select 233 GB
ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68A Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 2 795 GB
ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68A Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 2 795 GB
ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68A Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 2 795 GB
ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68A Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 2 795 GB
ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68W Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 3 726 GB
7SHKSN5W             Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 7 452 GB
7SHKSXWW             Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 7 452 GB
ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68M Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 5 589 GB
ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68L Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 5 589 GB
ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68L Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 5 589 GB
ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68L Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 5 589 GB
ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68L Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 5 589 GB
ATA SAMSUNG MZ7KM1T9 Healthy      SSD       SATA    Auto-Select 1 788 GB
ATA SAMSUNG MZ7KM1T9 Healthy      SSD       SATA    Auto-Select 1 788 GB
ATA SAMSUNG MZ7TE256 Healthy      SSD       SATA    Auto-Select 238 GB
ATA INTEL SSDSC2BX20 Healthy      SSD       SATA    Auto-Select 186 GB
```

First I marked three of the 3TB disks as retired and after the data was moved (Checked via Get-StorageJob) I removed three disks from the pool without error message.
Then I plugged in the three new hard drives and tried to add the disks to the pool.

```
$disks
    FriendlyName         HealthStatus MediaType BusType Usage       Size
    ------------         ------------ --------- ------- -----       ----
    ATA HGST HUH721212AL Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 11 176GB
    ATA HGST HUH721212AL Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 11 176GB
    ATA HGST HUH721212AL Healthy      HDD       SAS     Auto-Select 11 176GB

    Add-PhysicalDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName StoragePool10 -PhysicalDisks $disks
```

But here I get the error message that the operation is not supported.

```
Add-PhysicalDisk : One or more physical disks are not supported by this operation.

Extended information:
One or more physical disks encountered an error during addition to the storage pool.
```

I can't find any further information and can't find the reason why adding a bigger disk is not supported.

Server: MS Server 2016 / Controller: LSI 9211-8I - IT mode (already changed the controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this message is the different LogicalSector Size - my new disks use 4k (native), all other disks have either a size of 512b (native) or 4k (512e mode)

According to the "Software-Defined Storage Design Considerations Guide" this is not supported...

> you can’t add 4K native disks to a pool that uses 512 byte sectors for
>   virtual disks, so if you think you might ever add a 4K native disk to
>   the pool (such as when replacing a failed disk), create your pools
>   with 4 KB logical sectors, even if you don’t yet have any 4K native
>   disks.